# How to fix the remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#

I use website html then very good but I change "baseurl" to php then error:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

My code here:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

// Add a user agent header in case the requested URI contains a query.
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR1.0.3705;)");

string baseurl = "http://mn244.com/ip/1.php";

Stream data = client.OpenRead(baseurl);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
data.Close();
reader.Close();
s = s.Replace("<html><head><title>IP Address - Kool</title></head><body>", "").Replace("</body></html>", "").ToString();
```

Comment: There is no issue with your code, your website is not opening, change base url to `https://www.google.com/`, it will work.

Comment: Sorry, It is "http://mn244.com/ip/1.php" Please help me